# Is Transaction outbox highly reliable

Tags: masstransit

I want to know how Transaction outbox works and how MT guarantees the consistency of database transactions and message sending operations.

In the aspnetcore MVC example, when the database transaction is successfully submitted, but the message fails to be sent for some reason, will the MT retry sending the message?

I don't see any configuration about database storage, I'm thinking about how this reliability is guaranteed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the documentation, the TransactionOutbox feature ensures that the transaction only commits when all the messages that were sent or published from the consumer context are actually sent to the message bus.

MassTransit *always* retries to send the message if the transport doesn't acknowledge the message. It is not part of the outbox anyway.

If the transport fails to send or publish your messages, there will be no commit, so the transaction will rollback.

Comment: I think question might be referring to this [newer addition of a TransactionOutbox](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/transactions.html#transaction-outbox) outside the scope of a Consumer.

It should yes. Because if it fails to publish, it will get an exception, and rollback the DB.

Comment: If the message is sent successfully, the database transaction fails for some reason, which will cause the application data to be abnormal. Because the message has already been sent, its consumers will consume these messages, am I right?

Comment: @maldworth that's the one I was referring to. The in-memory outbox just doesn't send anything if the consumer fails.

Comment: @dingsongjie I believe it won't send anything if the transaction fails. That's why it uses the TransactionScope, not the database transaction, for example. As a consequence, I don't think it will be very fast, but it should work. You need to ensure that the transport you choose supports the TransactionScope.